# Will biginteger equivalent be introduced in the c++1y standard

Tags: c++, std, c++14

I remember a while ago I heard that there were thoughts of including a BigInteger implementation in the c++0x standard(as it was called back then). Apparently this did not happen but I was wondering if this is planned as part of c++1y or not.

Comment: why is this question negativ rated? i there also was a boost project for something similar, i think about 4-5 years ago. and there is still one in the boost sandbox named [big_number](https://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/big_number/). in my opinion this question is legitimately.

Comment: @itwasntpete: Boost has an officially released library, [Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html), which includes, among other things, support for unbounded integers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley :D didn't noticed that before (maybe bacause our current boost is 1.51.0). thank you.

Comment: @itwasntpete - the edit to the question fixed the problem, and those who downvoted the original question or voted to close it need to undo.

Comment: While I think this question is not a perfect fit for stack overflow (iso open mailing lists are probably the right place), but closing it as "primarily opinion-based"??? How is it opinion based?

Comment: @JohanLundberg It's about a standard that isn't defined yet. It's definition may change, and there are only opinions about if it will or not. Facts are unknown until it's done, and then question should be "is ... introduced", not "will it be".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discussion of a standard (inclusion of something or not). Additionally looking at the draft could answer this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest official paper on the subject is [N3542](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3542.html).  It is not slated for inclusion in C++14.

Answer (score 6):

The unbounded integer library is being worked on in SG6, the Numerics study group. It will probably go into a Technical Specification (TS, what used to be called a TR) once we sort out a few things about its interface and about interoperability of library numeric types.

Comment: Aren't TS and TR fundamentally different things? [TS is normative](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=ts) and has a schedule associated with it, [TR is informative](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards_development/deliverables-all.htm?type=tr) and can be just a piece of prose (like the old C++ Performance TR, 18015:2006)

Comment: TR stood for "Technical Report", but the terminology was changed a year or so ago, and TR got the axe. What used to be a TR is now a class something-or-other Technical Specification, TS for short.

Comment: it still stands for "Technical Report" in the list of ISO deliverables, and I see TRs published in 2013, e.g. 29154:2013. Sounds like they were split rather than axed.

Comment: @Cubbi - yes, there's a transition going on. Projects that were working toward a TR don't have to change to a TS. My understanding is that going forward, new projects will be TS's rather than TR's.